# Solving a 2nd order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Any suggestions to solve for u:

$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \xi\partial \eta}= \frac{-au}{4}$

Where u is a function of $\xi$ and $\eta$

I tried integrating first with respect to $\xi$ and then $\eta$ but quickly realised this meant there would be a u on both sides which wouldn't easily resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look for solutions of the form $\exp(c\xi + d \eta)$, and take linear combinations...